# How to load a function method after facebook social plugin is has finished loaded?

Tags: jquery-plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I have jQuery masonry to layout the list items on my website, each list item has a fb:comments. Loading SDK asynchronously, even putting the method "$container.masonry( 'reload' );" after FB.init() the list items are still overlapping.

I tested putting an alert() box before reload masonry, if close the alert box quickly the items are still overlapping but if close it after a while it display correctly with margin. So I assume the masonry reload runs before the content of fb:comments finish loaded.

How do I trigger masonry reload after the content of fb:comments finish loaded? Not by button click. Images show when it's overlapping and masonry reload after fb:comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use xfbml version of plugins, you can subscribe to xfbml.render - fired when all plugin (calls) completes.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Worked for me, too. If you want to see my working code example, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449193/facebook-like-box-load-event-jquery/19295464#19295464

Answer (score 2):

As per the [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8#xfbml-example), there is a loading event which will be triggered automatically when the page will finish rendering plugins

**Step-1:** In the HTML (put it where you want the social box to be shown):

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

**Step-2:** In the footer (just before ending the `<body>` tag):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    //FB.init({ status: false, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function(){
        SocialBoxesLoaded(); //-->this is what we want (any custom Function) :)
    });
};
(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function SocialBoxesLoaded(){
    //...Your Custom Code...
}
</script>
```