# fb-like plugin - Execute code after facebook plugins are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have included the fb-like plugin in a website that shows tooltips when the mouse is over any elements that have a `title` property.

The issue is that the facebook plugin adds a title attribute to the iframe, which is loaded after, and I can't seem to find a way to remove it.

The facebook plugin code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="facebook.com/saekthmey"; data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

It generates:

```
<iframe class="" src="http://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/like.php?action=recommend&amp;app_id=1098294926865015&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F1ldYU13brY_.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1931e415abd1ea%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Ff37c5673a2d1dae%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=294&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsaekthmey&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;sdk=joey&amp;share=true&amp;show_faces=true" style="border: medium none; visibility: visible; width: 450px; height: 57px;" title="fb:like Facebook Social Plugin" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" name="f305ebf93e709ca" frameborder="0" height="1000px" width="1000px"></iframe>
```

I assume there is something like this somewhere in the website `$('*[title]).tooltip()` but I am not going to remove it anyway.

In other words, I need to execute code after the plugin is loaded.

I found this: [Facebook like box load event jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449193/facebook-like-box-load-event-jquery/19295464#19295464) but it did not work.

Comment: show us the code, at least the code pertinent to the question

Comment: It generates an iframe which contains a title attribute. I do not know exactly where the tooltips are assigned to elements containing a title elements because I did not build the website but I assume it is something like this somewhere $('*[title]).tooltip(). I am not going to remove that anyway. 

I need a way to execute javascript AFTER the plugins are loaded

Comment: place it into the question, in a code block

Comment: I found this but it did not work for me. It is quite an old post, the SDK might have changed since then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449193/facebook-like-box-load-event-jquery/19295464#19295464